# how to run a Router.route() in a reactive way

Tags: meteor, iron-router

if I understand [this](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#reactivity) correctly I can use Session.get() to re-run a Router.route(), however it's not working for me. this one of my route:

```
Router.route("dashboard", function () {
    "use strict";

    var env = Session.get("ENV");
    console.log(env, "router-unisight");
    if (env && (env.indexOf("all") === 0 || env.indexOf("unisight") !== -1)) {
        this.subscribe("dashboards");
        this.subscribe("uTree").wait();

        if (this.ready()) {
            this.render("dashboard");
            this.render("toolbar", {to: "subheader"});
        } else {
            this.render("loading");
        }
    } else {
        this.render("notfound");
    }
});
```

I have a console.log() that displays only once and I know for a fact that after `Session.setDefault("ENV", null);` is called this variable is changes one more time

so the question is how can I re-run a route after a Session variable changes?

Answer (score 0):

The route needs to be used by a client before you see the console message. Iron router typically provide client side routes so you won't see the console.log on server side. here is a raw app that shows this working:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/xCG9Epeo3pTYZbLJF/Leaderboard

Comment: this route is in the client already and it's been used, when I go http://localhost:3000/dashboard (this route) I, only see one message in the browser dev console, when I should see the same console.log with two different values (the second message should show up when the route is re-run)